# Are PostgreSQL functions transactional?

Tags: database, postgresql, transactions, atomic

Is a PostgreSQL function such as the following automatically transactional?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_materialized_view(name)
  RETURNS integer AS
$BODY$
 DECLARE
     _table_name ALIAS FOR $1;
     _entry materialized_views%ROWTYPE;
     _result INT;
 BEGIN          

     EXECUTE 'TRUNCATE TABLE ' || _table_name;

     UPDATE materialized_views
     SET    last_refresh = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
     WHERE  table_name = _table_name;

     RETURN 1;
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER;
```

In other words, if an error occurs during the execution of the function, will any changes be *rolled back*? If this isn't the default behavior, how can I make the function *transactional*?

Comment: @FrankHeikens my question is "will changes be automtically rolled-back after an error", rather than "will changes be rolled-back if I execute ROLLBACK"

Comment: @Don Be aware that `TRUNCATE` has, or used to have, some somewhat funky transactional behaviour. I don't remember the specifics; search the pgsql-general archives.

Comment: Yes, functions are transactional, even if written in `LANGUAGE SQL`.

Comment: @CraigRinger As far as I can tell `TRUNCATE` ignores all savepoints and just destroys your table data outright

Answer (score 107):

**PostgreSQL 12 update**: [there is limited support for top-level `PROCEDURE`s that can do transaction control](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html). You still cannot manage transactions in regular SQL-callable functions, so the below remains true except when using the new top-level procedures.

---

Functions are part of the transaction they're called from. Their effects are rolled back if the transaction rolls back. Their work commits if the transaction commits. Any `BEGIN ... EXCEPT` blocks within the function operate like (and under the hood use) savepoints like the `SAVEPOINT` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT` SQL statements.

The function either succeeds in its entirety or fails in its entirety, barring `BEGIN ... EXCEPT` error handling. If an error is raised within the function and not handled, the transaction calling the function is aborted. Aborted transactions cannot commit, and if they try to commit the `COMMIT` is treated as `ROLLBACK`, same as for any other transaction in error. Observe:

```
regress=# BEGIN;
BEGIN
regress=# SELECT 1/0;
ERROR:  division by zero
regress=# COMMIT;
ROLLBACK
```

See how the transaction, which is in the error state due to the zero division, rolls back on `COMMIT`?

If you call a function without an explicit surounding transaction the rules are exactly the same as for any other Pg statement:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT refresh_materialized_view(name);
COMMIT;
```

(where `COMMIT` will fail if the `SELECT` raised an error).

PostgreSQL does not (yet) support autonomous transactions in functions, where the procedure/function could commit/rollback independently of the calling transaction. This can be simulated using a new session via [dblink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22353286/32453).

**BUT**, things that aren't transactional or are imperfectly transactional exist in PostgreSQL. If it has non-transactional behaviour in a normal `BEGIN; do stuff; COMMIT;` block, it has non-transactional behaviour in a function too. For example, `nextval` and `setval`, `TRUNCATE`, etc.

Comment: Very clear explanation. Special thanks for illustrating your answer with short and to the point examples.

Comment: I believe you can now perform an actual commit inside a procedure, since PG11. https://blog.dbi-services.com/postgresql-11-procedures-and-transaction-control/

Comment: (and more info here in official docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-transactions.html )

Comment: @craig-ringer What did you mean by "limited" support of procedures? Why is it limited?

Answer (score 44):

As my knowledge of PostgreSQL isn't as deep as Craig Ringer´s I will try to give a shorter answer: Yes.

If you execute a function that has an error in it, none of the steps will impact in the database.

Also, if you execute a query in `PgAdmin` the same happen.

For example, if you execute in a query:

```
update your_table yt set column1 = 10 where yt.id=20;

select anything_that_do_not_exists;
```

The update in the row, `id = 20` of `your_table` will not be saved in the database.

**UPDATE Sep - 2018**

To clarify the concept I have made a little example with non-transactional function nextval.

First, let´s create a sequence:

`create sequence test_sequence start 100;`

Then, let´s execute:

`update your_table yt set column1 = 10 where yt.id=20; select nextval('test_sequence'); select anything_that_do_not_exists;`

Now, if we open another query and execute

`select nextval('test_sequence');`

We will get 101 because the first value (100) was used in the latter query (that is because the sequences are not transactional) although the update was not committed.

Comment: Thank you for the clear crisp answer! After reading Craig's answer I was left feeling unsure.

Comment: much better answer than Craig's

Comment: Beware of non-transactional things like `nextval` though; if they're not transactional or not fully transactional as normal queries, they aren't in functions either.

Answer (score 12):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-structure.html

> It is important not to confuse the use of BEGIN/END for grouping statements in PL/pgSQL with the similarly-named SQL commands for transaction control. PL/pgSQL's BEGIN/END are only for grouping; they do not start or end a transaction. Functions and trigger procedures are always executed within a transaction established by an outer query — they cannot start or commit that transaction, since there would be no context for them to execute in. However, a block containing an EXCEPTION clause effectively forms a subtransaction that can be rolled back without affecting the outer transaction. For more about that see Section 39.6.6.

Answer (score 7):

In the function level, it is not transnational. In other words, each statement in the function belongs to a single transaction, which is the default db auto commit value. Auto commit is true by default. But anyway, you have to call the function using

`select schemaName.functionName()`

The above statement 'select schemaName.functionName()' is a single transaction, let's name the transaction T1, and so the all the statements in the function belong to the transaction T1. In this way, the function is in a single transaction.

Comment: Thats not true at all. Functions are always atomic.

Answer (score 6):

Postgres 14 update: All statements written in between the `BEGIN` and `END` block of a Procedure/Function is executed in a single transaction. Thus, any errors arising while execution of this block will cause automatic roll back of the transaction.

Comment: For PostgreSQL 15: "By default, any error occurring in a PL/pgSQL function aborts execution of the function and the surrounding transaction." Cfr. [43.6.8. Trapping Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING)

Comment: `BEGIN ... END;` is not transaction. `BEGIN ... END;` is just the statement to have multiple statements. `BEGIN; ... COMMIT;` is actually transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a function and procedure are transactional(atomic) in PostgreSQL. A function and procedure are run in a transaction so if there is error, the transaction is rollbacked.

For example, you create `my_func()` function which sets `5` to `my.var` then can cause `division by zero` error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func(value INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
SET my.var = 5; -- Here
RETURN 1/value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_func(1)` then `5` is set to `my.var` successfully as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# SELECT my_func(1);
 my_func
---------
       1
(1 row)
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 5
(1 row)
```

Now, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_func(0)` then `division by zero`  error occurs, then `my.var` is still `2` as shown below because `my_func()` function is rollbacked:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# SELECT my_func(0);
ERROR:  division by zero
...
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 2
(1 row)
```

And for example, you create `my_proc()` procedure which sets `5` to `my.var` then can cause `division by zero` error as shown below:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc(INOUT value INTEGER) AS $$
BEGIN
SET my.var = 5; -- Here
SELECT 1/value INTO value;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

First, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_proc(1)` then `5` is set to `my.var` successfully as shown below:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# CALL my_proc(1);
 my_func
---------
       1
(1 row)
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 5
(1 row)
```

Now, you set `2` to `my.var`, then call `my_proc(0)` then `division by zero`  error occurs, then `my.var` is still `2` as shown below because `my_proc()` procedure is rollbacked:

```sql
postgres=# SET my.var = 2;
SET
postgres=# CALL my_proc(0);
ERROR:  division by zero
...
postgres=# SELECT current_setting('my.var');
 current_setting
-----------------
 2
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the ATOMIC Transaction including triggers as well.