# equivalent of pragma autonomous_transaction of Oracle in postgres

Tags: oracle, postgresql, transactions, pragma

In oracle there is a built in way to make a transaction autonomous, but in Postgres there is none (still, as far as I know). What should one do in pl/pgsql code to make an equivalency of autonomous transaction functionality in Postgres? Any hack or by pass in coding guide would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Committing transactions while executing a postgreql Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22351039/committing-transactions-while-executing-a-postgreql-function)

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the way to do this is to use a connection from the database to itself with the [`dblink`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) contrib module.

Comment: **dblink is a module that supports connections to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database session**
as the documentation says.

Comment: Right. But you can of course also connect to to a database from itself.