# SQL: Reuse value returned by function?

Tags: sql, postgresql, variables, sql-insert, sql-function

1. How do I reuse the value returned by `pair` called in the function below?

   ```
   CREATE FUNCTION messages_add(bigint, bigint, text) RETURNS void AS $$
       INSERT INTO chats SELECT pair($1, $2), $1, $2
           WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chats WHERE id = pair($1, $2));
       INSERT INTO messages VALUES (pair($1, $2), $1, $3);
   $$ LANGUAGE SQL;
   ```

   I know that the [SQL query language doesn't support storing simple values in variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959/how-do-you-use-script-variables-in-postgresql) as does a typical programming language. So, I looked at [`WITH` Queries (Common Table Expressions)](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html), but I'm not sure if I should use `WITH`, and anyway, I couldn't figure out the correct syntax for what I'm doing.
2. Here's my [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d6454/3) and my original question about [storing chats & messages in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367688/messages-query-a-users-chats). This function [inserts-if-not-exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18654976/242933) then inserts. I'm not using a transaction because I want to keep things fast, and storing a chat without messages is not so bad but worse the other way around. So, query order matters. If there's a better way to do things, please advise.
3. I want to reuse the value mainly to speed up the code. But, does the SQL interpreter automatically optimize the function above anyway? Still, I want to write good, [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function body is procedural, use the [`plpgsql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) language as opposed to SQL:

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_add(bigint, bigint, text) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO chats
        SELECT pair($1, $2), $1, $2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chats WHERE id = pair($1, $2));
    INSERT INTO messages VALUES (pair($1, $2), $1, $3);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Also, if the result to reuse is `pair($1,$2)` you may store it into a variable:

```
CREATE FUNCTION messages_add(bigint, bigint, text) RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
    pair bigint := pair($1, $2);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO chats
        SELECT pair, $1, $2
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chats WHERE id = pair);
    INSERT INTO messages VALUES (pair, $1, $3);
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why does the function body being procedural merit using PL/pgSQL?

Comment: @MattDiPasquale: PL stands for procedural language, it provides what SQL lacks in terms of variables and execution control. The advantage of SQL as a func language is the potential inlining of single SELECTs, but it doesn't apply in this case of two INSERTs.

Answer (score 1):

```
create function messages_add(bigint, bigint, text) returns void as $$
    with p as (
        select pair($1, $2) as p
    ), i as (
        insert into chats
        select (select p from p), $1, $2
        where not exists (
            select 1
            from chats
            where id = (select p from p)
        )
    )
    insert into messages
    select (select p from p), $1, $3
    where exists (
        select 1
        from chats
        where id = (select p from p)
    )
    ;
$$ language sql;
```

It will only insert into messages if it exists in chats.

Comment: Thanks, Clodoaldo! But, I want it to insert into `messages` even if the row already exists in `chats` so that you can add multiple messages to one chat. By chat, I mean conversation, or thread.

Answer (score 0):

1. I actually don't have an answer for this part of your question, but I'll address it anyway because [Markdown *SUCKS* and Stack Overflow doesn't support the `start` attribute on the `ol` element](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137077/cant-start-a-numbered-list-on-a-number-other-than-1).
2. OK. Now, that we're at 2, :-) [PostgreSQL functions are transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778209/are-postgres-functions-transactional). So, order actually doesn't matter since both inserts will be committed together in one transaction.
3. No, the optimizer only pre-evaluates immutable functions when they're called with constant (not variable) arguments, e.g., `pair(4, 5)`. See [Function Volatility Categories](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-volatility.html).