# postgres functions and transactions with BEGIN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.5

I have some questions about how postgres functions and transactions work.

Currently my function looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_function(some_id character varying)
    RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    S1;
    S2;
    S3;
    .
    .
    Sn;
RETURN some_id;
END; $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
```

The statements can be `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or plain `SELECT` queries based on `some_id`. As I understand from postgre [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-begin.html), all statements in this function are executed as a single transaction and committed at the END.

My questions are:

1. if lets say `S1` is successful but `S2`  fails, will `S1` get committed?
2. is my understanding that, all statements after `BEGIN` are executed as a single trasaction, correct?
3. in the absence of an explicit `COMMIT` before `END` and all statements are successful, will the transaction be committed regardless of autocommit = on/off ?
4. lets say `S1, S2, S3` are all `INSERT` statements. `S1` and `S2` succeed but `S3` fails, will the inserts in `S1, S2` be reversed in the absence of an explicit `ROLLBACK` statement?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are PostgreSQL functions transactional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778209/are-postgresql-functions-transactional)

Comment: `BEGIN` and `END` here are used just for grouping statements in the function, they do not start or end a transaction

Answer (score 5):

Answers by number:

1. No; if `S2` fails, the whole transaction is aborted and can only be rolled back.
2. There is probably a misunderstanding. The SQL statement `BEGIN` that starts a transaction is something quite different from the `BEGIN` that starts a PL/pgSQL block. The latter does *not* start a transaction.

   If there was no explicit SQL command `BEGIN`, every statement runs in its own transaction (“autocommit”).

   All statements in a function are executed in a single transaction.
3. You cannot have `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`) in a function.
4. Yes. This is the same question as 1., only in the negative.

Comment: just to be clear about your answer for 4: 'YES' the inserted rows by `S1, S2` will be reversed in the absence of explicit `ROLLBACK`. Right?

Comment: That's what I mean. Even if you try to commit the transaction, it will be rolled back (because it is aborted).